# Converting Workbook object to File object

Tags: java, excel, file, file-conversion

I have the workbook object of type:

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
Workbook mybook;
```

I want to convert the same object to File:

```
java.io.File
File File;
```

How can I do that?

Comment: A `File` object is an abstract representation of a file or a directory on the filesystem, a `Workbook` doesn't just magically convert to it.

Comment: So is there any Reference which i can use for the conversion. @Kayaman

Comment: You can't convert it. You can write it to disk and then you can refer to it with a `File` object.